# Alternating block and inline behavior with div elements?

Tags: html, css

So I have a table that I'm trying to make. Essentially, it will be two rows of three images each, with very short text below each one.

My structure looks like this:

```
<div class="mission-statement-1">
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mission-statement-2">
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the two main div elements with display: block with a width of 100%, so that they'd be one under the other. The inner divs are display: inline, so that they would be next to each other, and are given a width of 30%.

If I have just images alone, this works as intended. However, I'm trying to have the text centered underneath each image, and adding text will mess up the intended layout. If I use a block text element, such as a p, then I'll have six rows of one item each. If I stick with the span, then the text comes after the image (as it should given its inline property). I can't seem to make it work the way that I want it to.

Any help?

Comment: You can use `display: table` and the other table-related CSS elements, or better yet look into flexbox.

Comment: You can wrap the image and the span in a nother span

Comment: You can try html tag  <figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>

Comment: what size are image ? , are they suppose to fill entire width of their containers, is there a max and min-width to mind about, are these boxes meant to pile on top of each others on small screen, ? what css have you tried so far ?

Comment: What are you talking about? It can be an easy fix but you need to describe it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flex with some CSS. It'll also work as a better way to have a responsive table that's mobile friendly. Also, use the tags Figure and FigCaption which will basically glue the text to the images.

```css
.parent-wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
   
}
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent-wrapper">
        
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
            <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
            <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
        </div>    
        
        <div class="parent">        
         <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
            <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
            <div class="child"><figure><img src="http://media.nbcwashington.com/designimages/ots_dark_wx_103.png" /><figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
            </figure></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>        
              
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your inner `div`s `display: inline-block;`.

`inline-block` elements maintain the support of `block` styles, such as defined width and height, but can be rendered next to other objects like `inline` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mission-statement-1,
.mission-statement-2{
display:block;
}
.iconDiv{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
}
img{
background-color:green;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mission-statement-1">
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
    <figcaption>Some text1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
    <figcaption>Some text2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" >
    <figcaption>Some text3</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>

<div class="mission-statement-2">
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" >
    <figcaption>Some text4</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
    <figcaption>Some text5</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="iconDiv">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" >
    <figcaption>Some text6</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

You can Html figure and figcaption tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example about `flex`, and breaking point that can set to let content wrap if need. You can inspire yourself from it and dig into flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The snippet below uses `figure` and `figcaption`, HTML tags  dedicated to this kind of content,  and `flex` and `flex-wrap` for the CSS part.

`min` or `max-width` can be used to enhance your styling and set some basic breaking points unless you want also or only use media queries.

```css
.imgcpt {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid;
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

figcaption>* {
  margin: 0.25em
}
```

```html
<div class="imgcpt">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/201/100/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/102/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/203/103/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/204/104/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/205/105/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>Single title</h1>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/206/106/" alt="i show ..." />
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Or just simple text caption</p>
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Run snippet in fullpage or play with it and edit it @ http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dvoQyR

Not so much CSS has to be used when using flex.